# Build up IQueryable including additional tables based on conditions

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I have an issue where we create a complex `IQueryable` that we need to make it more efficient.

There are 2 tables that should only be included if columns from them are being filtered.

My exact situation is complex to explain so I thought I could illustrate it with an example for cars.

If I have a `CarFilter` class like this:

```
public class CarFilter
{
    public string BrandName { get;set; }
    public decimal SalePrice {get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that we have a query for car sales:

```
var info = from car in cars
           from carSale in carSales on carSale.BrandId == car.BrandId && car.ModelId == carSale.ModelId
           from brand in carBrands on car.BrandId == brand.BrandId
           select car

 var cars = info.ToList();
```

Let's say that this is a huge query that returns 100'000 rows as we are looking at cars and sales and the associated brands.

The user only wants to see the details from car, the other 2 tables are for filtering purposes.

So if the user only wants to see Ford cars, our logic above is not efficient. We are joining in the huge car sale table for no reason as well as `CarBrand` as the user doesn't care about anything in there.

My question is how can I only include tables in my `IQueryable` if they are actually needed?

So if there is a `BrandName` in my filter I would include `CarBrand` table, if not, it's not included.

Using this example, the only time I would ever want both tables is if the user specified both a `BrandName` and `SalePrice`.

The semantics are not important here, i.e the number of records returned being impacted by the joins etc, I am looking for help on the approach

I am using EF Core

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for complex filtering. Just join when it is needed.

```cs
var query = cars;

if (filter.SalePrice > 0)
{
    query =  
        from car in query
        join carSale in carSales on new { car.BrandId, car.ModelId } equals new { carSale.BrandId, carSale.ModelId }
        where carSale.Price >= filter.SalePrice
        select car;
}

if (!filter.BrandName.IsNullOrEempty())
{
    query = 
        from car in query
        join brand in carBrands on car.BrandId equals brand.BrandId
        where brand.Name == filter.BrandName
        select car;
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: How can I then customize my select statement?  I.e. select different fields from the tables? For example, select car.BrandId and Brand.Name?

Comment: Well it is different question. And I didn't get it. Which result do you expect?. Better to create new SO question for that.